# Django error message: ["'on' value must be either True or False."]

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm currently having this error message on django: ["'on' value must be either True or False."]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Comment
from .forms import sign

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'submits/index.html')

def sign_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sign(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_contact = Comment(email=request.POST['email'], message=request.POST['message'], checkbox=request.POST['checkbox'])
            new_contact.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = sign()

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'submits/sign.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class sign(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=500,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'type' : 'email',  'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Enter your email', 'aria-describedby' : 'emailHelp'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={ 'class' : 'form-control', 'rows' : '3', 'placeholder' : 'Write your proposal'}))
    checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    checkbox_attributes={'class': 'form-check'}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Comment(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    message = models.TextField()
    checkbox = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return 'e-mail: {}, ID: {}'.format(self.email, self.id)
```

**Providing the full traceback**

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact_us/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['submits',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
Traceback:
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/media/joaomjaneiro/LEXAR/django projects/love/submits/views.py" in sign_list
  14.             new_contact.save()
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  759.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  842.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  880.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1125.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1282.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  1235.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1235.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1234.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in prepare_value
  1174.             value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  767.         return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  762.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1024.         return self.to_python(value)
File "/home/joaomjaneiro/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
  1017.             params={'value': value},
Exception Type: ValidationError at /contact_us/
Exception Value: ["'on' value must be either True or False."]
```

In the HTML file I have the forms.checkbox and not a hard coded one, I can't seem to figure this out

I really can't understand how to fix this error

Comment: Most of the time, this issue occurs because you actually send `on` as the result of an HTML Checkbox.. whereas Django expects True or False.  You already have this `checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)`, use it in form instead of your own HTML checkbox

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve this using below code:

```
if is_retired == 'on':
   is_retired = True
else:
   is_retired = False
```

I have found that I have declared `is_retired` as ***Boolean***-field but in my project I am assigning a ***string*** value either 'on' or 'off'.

So as a solution I am converting the string value to a Boolean value.

Comment: The `if/else` is really redundant here (as comparation already returns a boolean). This can just be `is_retired = is_retired == 'on'`

Answer (score 0):

```
True if form.data.get("status") == "on" else False
```

also possible.

Comment: Why the ternary? `==` already returns a boolean. This is equivalent to just `form.data.get("status") == "on"`

Comment: I see. That is possible too. :)